# Not able to publish to Azure Function Apps to Azure Service Environment using VS Code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-service-plan

I have created an ASE (Azure Service Environment). Inside that we have a Service Plan and a function app on that plan.

When I try to publish the function app from the visual studio code, it is giving me the error -

```
Request to https://my-function-service.scm.mydemo.appserviceenvironment.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true&author=VS%20Code failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my-function-service.scm.mydemo.appserviceenvironment.net
```

I've tried the push the code from my local machine as well as from Virtual machine hosted on the same Virtual Network as ASE.

Any ideas where I'm doing wrong?

**Note- ** I have changed the service name in above link.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/2032 ?

Comment: Already went through those, no luck

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase#publishing

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please check your app service environment type. The app service environment has two types: External ASE and  ILB ASE. The different type has different deployment configurations.

With an External ASE, we can use the same way with normal function app to publish.

With an ILB ASE, the publishing endpoints are only available through the ILB. The ILB is on a private IP in the ASE subnet in the virtual network. If you don't have network access to the ILB, you can't publish any apps on that ASE. Meanwhile, you must configure DNS for the apps in the system. Otherwise, you also cannot publish. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase#publishing) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase#dns-configuration)